# How do I initialize a char** from a different function?

Tags: c

I am getting a segmentation fault on the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h> 

void init_test(char ***test) {
    *test = malloc(2 * sizeof(char *));
    *test[0] = malloc(3); 
    *test[1] = malloc(3); 
    strcpy(*test[0], "12"); 
    strcpy(*test[1], "13"); 
}

int main()
{
    char **test = NULL;
    init_test(&test); 
    printf("1: %s, 2: %s", test[0], test[1]); 
    printf("Hello World");
    return 0;
}
```

I have couple of different variations of this, but I am not sure how to correctly initialize a char** in a different function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a matter of [*operator precedence*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence). The expression `*test[0]` is equal to `*(test[0])`, not `(*test)[0]` as you seem to expect.

Answer (score 1):

The array index operator has higher precedence than the dereference operator.  You need to add parenthesis:

```
(*test)[0] = malloc(3); 
(*test)[1] = malloc(3); 
strcpy((*test)[0], "12"); 
strcpy((*test)[1], "13");
```